# Invalid blueprint: route when using angular cli and 404: page missing

Tags: angular

I followed/clone this [github repo](https://github.com/linnovate/mean):

In my project, I type: `ng generate route task`, then I got this error.

> Invalid blueprint: route

I search the stackoverflow, only 2 posts related to my quetion, but did not find the useful answer.

Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "angular-starter",
  "version": "6.0.0",
  "description": "An Angular Webpack Starter kit featuring Angular (Router, Http, Forms, Services, Tests, E2E, Coverage), Karma, Protractor, Jasmine, Istanbul, TypeScript, and Webpack by AngularClass",
  "keywords": [
    "angular",
    "angular2",
    "angular4",
    "webpack",
    "typescript"
  ],
  "author": "Patrick Stapleton <patrick@angularclass.com>",
  "homepage": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "build:aot:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run clean:aot && cross-env BUILD_AOT=1 npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build:aot": "npm run build:aot:prod",
    "build:dev": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --progress --profile",
    "build:docker": "npm run build:prod && docker build -t angular2-webpack-start:latest .",
    "build:prod": "npm run clean:dist && npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.prod.js  --progress --profile --bail",
    "build": "npm run build:dev",
    "ci:aot": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:jit": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e",
    "ci:nobuild": "npm run lint && npm test && npm run e2e",
    "ci:testall": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:prod && npm run e2e && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e",
    "ci:travis": "npm run lint && npm run test && npm run build:aot && npm run e2e:travis",
    "ci": "npm run ci:testall",
    "clean:dll": "npm run rimraf -- dll",
    "clean:aot": "npm run rimraf -- compiled",
    "clean:dist": "npm run rimraf -- dist",
    "clean:install": "npm set progress=false && npm install",
    "clean": "npm cache clean --force && npm run rimraf -- node_modules doc coverage dist compiled dll",
    "docker": "docker",
    "docs": "npm run typedoc -- --options typedoc.json --exclude '**/*.spec.ts' ./src/",
    "e2e:live": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:live",
    "e2e:travis": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor:delay",
    "e2e": "npm-run-all -p -r server:prod:ci protractor",
    "github-deploy:dev": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubDev",
    "github-deploy:prod": "npm run webpack -- --config config/webpack.github-deploy.js --progress --profile --env.githubProd",
    "github-deploy": "npm run github-deploy:dev",
    "lint": "npm run tslint \"src/**/*.ts\"",
    "node": "node",
    "postinstall": "npm run webdriver:update",
    "postversion": "git push && git push --tags",
    "preclean:install": "npm run clean",
    "preversion": "npm test",
    "protractor": "protractor",
    "protractor:delay": "sleep 3 && npm run protractor",
    "protractor:live": "protractor --elementExplorer",
    "rimraf": "rimraf",
    "server:dev:hmr": "npm run server:dev -- --inline --hot",
    "server:dev": "npm run webpack-dev-server -- --config config/webpack.dev.js --open --progress --profile --watch --content-base src/",
    "server:prod": "http-server dist -c-1 --cors",
    "server:prod:ci": "http-server dist -p 3000 -c-1 --cors",
    "server": "npm run server:dev",
    "start:hmr": "npm run server:dev:hmr",
    "start": "npm run server:dev",
    "test": "npm run lint && karma start",
    "tslint": "tslint",
    "typedoc": "typedoc",
    "version": "npm run build",
    "watch:dev:hmr": "npm run watch:dev -- --hot",
    "watch:dev": "npm run build:dev -- --watch",
    "watch:prod": "npm run build:prod -- --watch",
    "watch:test": "npm run test -- --auto-watch --no-single-run",
    "watch": "npm run watch:dev",
    "webdriver-manager": "webdriver-manager",
    "webdriver:start": "npm run webdriver-manager start",
    "webdriver:update": "webdriver-manager update",
    "webpack-dev-server": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack-dev-server/bin/webpack-dev-server.js",
    "webpack": "node --max_old_space_size=4096 node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/cli": "^1.2.1",
    "@angular/common": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/compiler": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/forms": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/http": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/platform-server": "~4.1.2",
    "@angular/router": "~4.1.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr": "~1.2.2",
    "@angularclass/hmr-loader": "~3.0.2",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "ie-shim": "^0.1.0",
    "reflect-metadata": "^0.1.10",
    "rxjs": "~5.0.2",
    "zone.js": "0.8.5"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~4.0.3",
    "@types/hammerjs": "^2.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.5.45",
    "@types/node": "^7.0.13",
    "@types/source-map": "^0.5.0",
    "@types/uglify-js": "^2.6.28",
    "@types/webpack": "^2.2.15",
    "add-asset-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.0.2",
    "angular2-template-loader": "^0.6.2",
    "assets-webpack-plugin": "^3.5.1",
    "awesome-typescript-loader": "~3.1.2",
    "codelyzer": "~2.1.1",
    "copy-webpack-plugin": "^4.0.1",
    "css-loader": "^0.28.0",
    "cross-env": "^5.0.0",
    "exports-loader": "^0.6.4",
    "expose-loader": "^0.7.3",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "~2.1.0",
    "file-loader": "^0.11.1",
    "find-root": "^1.0.0",
    "gh-pages": "^1.0.0",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.28.0",
    "imports-loader": "^0.7.1",
    "inline-manifest-webpack-plugin": "^3.0.1",
    "istanbul-instrumenter-loader": "2.0.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.5.2",
    "json-loader": "^0.5.4",
    "karma": "^1.6.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.1.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.3",
    "karma-remap-coverage": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-sourcemap-loader": "^0.3.7",
    "karma-webpack": "~2.0.3",
    "ng-router-loader": "^2.1.0",
    "ngc-webpack": "~2.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.5.2",
    "npm-run-all": "^4.0.2",
    "optimize-js-plugin": "0.0.4",
    "parse5": "^3.0.2",
    "preload-webpack-plugin": "^1.2.2",
    "protractor": "^5.1.1",
    "raw-loader": "0.5.1",
    "rimraf": "~2.6.1",
    "sass-loader": "^6.0.3",
    "script-ext-html-webpack-plugin": "^1.7.1",
    "source-map-loader": "^0.2.1",
    "string-replace-loader": "~1.2.0",
    "style-loader": "^0.18.1",
    "to-string-loader": "^1.1.5",
    "ts-node": "^3.0.2",
    "tslib": "^1.6.1",
    "tslint": "~4.5.1",
    "tslint-loader": "^3.5.2",
    "typedoc": "^0.7.1",
    "typescript": "~2.2.2",
    "url-loader": "^0.5.8",
    "webpack": "~2.6.1",
    "webpack-dev-middleware": "^1.10.1",
    "webpack-dev-server": "~2.4.2",
    "webpack-dll-bundles-plugin": "^1.0.0-beta.5",
    "webpack-merge": "~4.1.0"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter.git"
  },
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-starter/issues"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">= 4.2.1",
    "npm": ">= 3"
  }
}
```

Comment: It seems to me that 'Routes are no longer valid blueprints.' See : https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#generating-components-directives-pipes-and-services

Comment: I have read the link you mentioned before. But what is the solution for my question? Thanks

Comment: task is just a component, I use 'ng generate route task', this will create a component with route for me, am I right? I just want to create a component with route.

Comment: @Vega Yes, I did this way before. I did the 'ng g component task' first. Then I manually add the route. I think I need to go to app.routes.ts. I did it, in my UI, when I click 'Task', I got this error: 404: page missing

Comment: @Vega I did everything you mentioned, but I still got this error: In my UI, when I click 'Task', I got this error: 404: page missing

Answer (score 0):

I want to share how I solve this problem.

1. Use `ng generate component task` to generate a new component
2. Then manually add the route (go to app.routes.ts, see step 3) into my project.
3. In my app.routes.ts, adds following:

   export const ROUTES: Routes = [

   { path: '',      component: HomeComponent },

   { path: 'home',  component: HomeComponent },
     { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },

   { path: 'task', component: TaskComponent},

   { path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},

   { path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},

   { path: '**',    component: NoContentComponent },
   ];

---

Above is working. I faced a problem before when I route to task component:

> 404: page missing

I was doing something wrong here, I was put 'task' in the last, this is not working:

export const ROUTES: Routes = [

{ path: '', component: HomeComponent },

{ path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, { path: 'about', component: AboutComponent },

{ path: 'detail', loadChildren: './+detail#DetailModule'},

{ path: 'barrel', loadChildren: './+barrel#BarrelModule'},

{ path: '**', component: NoContentComponent },

**{ path: 'task', component: TaskComponent}**
];

Comment: Sure, { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent } will 'catch' evrything what wasn't declared before.

Comment: This means { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent }  should be always in the last?

Comment: Preferably you should do! Otherwise, regardless of where you navigate to, the router will instantiate the NocontentComponent component.

Comment: I google it, but I did not find any document explain why { path: '**', component: NoContentComponent } should be always in the last. Do you have any reference document for me?